# Add attribute dynamically to component in converter?

Tags: jsf-2

I wonder if should be possible to add an attribute to a component inside a converter? So inside the getAsString I would use uiComponent.addAttribute(). This seems to work 50% for me, the initial value is set, but when the converter is called later setting a new value the initial value is still retrieved.

Answer (score 1):

you should not do it this way since it breaks *separation of duties*. you should use a bean or a scope attribute instead.

but maybe this suits:

```
<h:inputText value="#{bean.someValue}" converter="#{bean}">
    <f:attribute name="attrName" value="#{bean.attrValue}"/>
</h:inputText>
```

and

```
@ManagedBean
public class Bean implements Converter
{
    private String someValue;
    private String attrValue;

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value)
    {
        attrValue = "uppercase";
        return someValue.toUpperCase();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value)
    {
        attrValue = "lowercase";
        return value.toLowerCase();
    }

    public String getSomeValue()
    {
        return someValue;
    }

    public void setSomeValue(String someValue)
    {
        this.someValue = someValue;
    }

    public String getAttrValue()
    {
        return attrValue;
    }

    public void setAttrValue(String attrValue)
    {
        this.attrValue = attrValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, this would work. Annoying to have to add that attribute everywhere though. Is there no way to get it to work w/o having to manipulate the facelet all the time?

Comment: you are pretending too much from jsf ;)